# Win32API: Identify which program is using a serial COM port

Tags: winapi, serial-port

Win32API environment.
I need to identify which program is using a particular serial COM port. For example, if putty has opened COM4 and I later try to start another program that also wants to open COM4, how can I discover that putty is the program preventing this?
In other words, assuming I already have a list of all ports installed on the system, how do I work backwards to discover which programs have opened which ports?

Comment: Use [PortMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/portmon.aspx) from SysInternals.

Comment: You can't, the operating system will not tell you.  The kernel considers it "forbidden knowledge".  It is, given that the most likely reason such info might be used is to TerminateProcess() the owner process.  The user always knows so just provide a good diagnostic message.  In the unlikely case his flabber is completed gasted then he can always use the SysInternals' Handle utility, although I don't think it lists serial ports.

Comment: Hans:  It must be possible to do what I want programmatically, because Process Explorer can do exactly that. PE can tell you which \devices are associated with a process, and then knowing the \devices, you can, by elimination, discover the serial COM port name (the association between the \device name and its value is defined in the Registry).   I just need some pointers toward the Win32API functions that will let me do this.

Comment: You can do it only from a special kernel mode driver using IoGetDeviceObjectPointer and KphQueryNameFileObject functions. This process is not simple.

Comment: @IanW you could do some reverse engineering on Process Explorer (or any other program that displays handle usage of COM ports) by looking at the list of imports in the .EXE. You'll be able to eliminate the bulk of the imports as obviously not related to getting open handle info. Hopefully that will leave you with relatively few APIs left to investigate.

Comment: Or you can read the sources of Process Hacker...